# How to keep JobIntentService running on Oreo?

Tags: android, android-service, android-job

I have two services. One of handles receiving call states. 
Other handles an overlay window.

My problem is I can't keep services running. I could refactor receiving call states service. It gets each states changes and runs like new jobs. But other one which shows overlay, I can't do the same. I need to keep overlay windows reference somewhere, and i don't want to do it. I need to keep that service running. I've tried to use isStopped method. This doesn't work how I need. I can also add while loop in onHandleWork, but it doesn't look like a proper solution. Could someone have a better idea for keeping services running on Android 8?

Comment: Make your service be a foreground service, via a `Notification` and `setForeground()`.

Comment: Problem is I don't have a notification. And I don't want to show notification for using foreground.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Sorry!

Comment: I converted back target sdk version to 25. It works well! :(

Comment: Note that if you are distributing through the Play Store, [having a low `targetSdkVersion` will not be an option for much longer](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/08/android-version-ratchet.html).

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution.
 
That was just a quick fix.